# Cannot split long subequations

Tags: align, subequations, split, gather

I do not seem to be able to split two long sub-equations. I've tried multline, align, split and a few other possibilities but none of them have worked; I reckon a main issue is that I've got brackets everywhere (very long equations indeed!).

What I'd like is to have only two numbered equations (1a and 1b) but for these equations to fit within a standard page width. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my working code, but I'm not sure where to go from here:

```
\begin{subequations}\label{eqn:MagneticField3D}
    \begin{gather}
        B_{x}(r,x)=\frac{N I \mu_{0}}{2\pi}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}}\left(\mathcal{K}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})+\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}}\left(\mathcal{K}(k(r,x+d/2)^{2})+\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right)\right), \\
        B_{r}(r,x)=\frac{N I \mu_{0}}{2\pi r}\left(\frac{x-d/2}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}}\left(-\mathcal{K}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})+\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right)-\frac{x+d/2}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}}\left(-\mathcal{K}(k(r,x+d/2)^{2})+\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right)\right).
    \end{gather}
\end{subequations}
```

Comment: `subequations` has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: Your equation is too long. Find some way to shorten it. I can't keep focus when reading such a long equation

Comment: @egreg I added keywords that were relevant to the question, I never said this was a source of the problem.

Comment: @JouleV thanks for the comment, if I could shorten them I would not have posted the question.

Comment: You can never split any `\left/right` constructions, manually scale them using the four `big` constructions, then things can be split. But you should really rewrite this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that does not require introducing new notation. It makes use of `align`, plus `\left.` and `\right.` where necessary, as well as `\vphantom` to get the correct sizing of the brackets and parentheses. I also changed the outer parentheses to square brackets because I think it's easier to read, but obviously that's a stylistic choice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eqn:MagneticField3D}

    \begin{align}
        B_{x}(r,x) = & \frac{N I \mu_{0}}{2\pi}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}}\left(\mathcal{K}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2}) 
        \vphantom{\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}} % to size the ( correctly
        \right.\right. \nonumber \\
        & \left.\left. +\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right) \right. \nonumber \\
       & \left. -\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}}\left(\mathcal{K}(k(r,x+d/2)^{2}) 
       \vphantom{\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}} % to size the ( correctly
       \right.\right. \nonumber \\
       &  \left.\left. +\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right)
       \vphantom{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}}} % to size the ] correctly
       \right], \\
        B_{r}(r,x) = & \frac{N I \mu_{0}}{2\pi r}\left[\frac{x-d/2}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}}\left(-\mathcal{K}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2}) 
        \vphantom{\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}} % to size the ( correctly
        \right.\right. \nonumber \\
            & \left.\left. +\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right) \right. \nonumber \\
    & \left. -\frac{x+d/2}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}}\left(-\mathcal{K}(k(r,x+d/2)^{2}) 
    \vphantom{\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}} % to size the ( correctly
    \right.\right. \nonumber \\
    & \left.\left. +\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right)
    \vphantom{\frac{x-d/2}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}}} % to size the ] correctly
    \right].
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also add some `\hspace` to bump out the second lines of the "inner" parentheses:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eqn:MagneticField3D}

    \begin{align}
        B_{x}(r,x) = & \frac{N I \mu_{0}}{2\pi}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}}\left(\mathcal{K}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2}) 
        \vphantom{\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}} % to size the ( correctly
        \right.\right. \nonumber \\
        & \hspace{1cm} \left.\left. +\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right) \right. \nonumber \\
       & \left. -\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}}\left(\mathcal{K}(k(r,x+d/2)^{2}) 
       \vphantom{\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}} % to size the ( correctly
       \right.\right. \nonumber \\
       &  \hspace{1cm} \left.\left. +\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right)
       \vphantom{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}}} % to size the ] correctly
       \right], \\
        B_{r}(r,x) = & \frac{N I \mu_{0}}{2\pi r}\left[\frac{x-d/2}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}}\left(-\mathcal{K}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2}) 
        \vphantom{\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}} % to size the ( correctly
        \right.\right. \nonumber \\
            & \hspace{1cm} \left.\left. +\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right) \right. \nonumber \\
    & \left. -\frac{x+d/2}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}}\left(-\mathcal{K}(k(r,x+d/2)^{2}) 
    \vphantom{\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}} % to size the ( correctly
    \right.\right. \nonumber \\
    & \hspace{1cm} \left.\left. +\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}\mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2})\right)
    \vphantom{\frac{x-d/2}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}}} % to size the ] correctly
    \right].
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

You can probably reduce it down to. Dues to the width of the remaining fractions, it did not seem forth it to reduce these.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

To reduce complexity, define
\begin{align*}
  A &= \frac{N I \mu_0}{2\pi}, \\
  B &= \sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}},\\
  C &= \mathcal{K}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2}), \\
  D &= \mathcal{E}(k(r,x-d/2)^{2}), \\
  E  &= \sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}, \\
  F &= \mathcal{K}(k(r,x+d/2)^{2}),
\end{align*}
\begin{subequations}\label{eqn:MagneticField3D}
  \begin{gather}
    \begin{aligned}[b]
      B_{x}(r,x)=A\Biggl(&\frac{1}{B}\Biggl(C+\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}D\Biggr)
      \\
      &-\frac{1}{E}\Biggl(F+\frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}D\Biggr)\Biggr),
    \end{aligned}
    \\
    \begin{aligned}[b]
      B_{r}(r,x)=
      \frac{A}{r}\Biggl(&\frac{x-d/2}{B}\Biggl(-C+\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x-d/2)^{2}}D\Biggr)
      \\
      &-\frac{x+d/2}{E}\Biggl(-F+\frac{a^{2}+r^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+(x+d/2)^{2}}D\Biggr)\Biggr).
    \end{aligned}
  \end{gather}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Quote from the OP: "if I could shorten them I would not have posted the question". Therefore shortening is not an answer, unfortunately

Comment: @JouleV the OP is using `\left/right` which cannot be broken. A lot of users does not know that.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, with `geometry` (for more sensible margins) and `nccmath` (for medium-sized formulæ, ~80 % of \displaystyle, and the `fleqn` environment):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eqn:MagneticField3D}
\begin{fleqn}
    \begin{gather}
\raisetag{11.5ex}
\begin{aligned}
B_{x}(r,x)= \medmath{\frac{N I \mu_{0}}{2\pi} \! \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+\bigl(x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}}}\Biggl(\mathcal{K}\Bigl(k\bigl(r,x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}\Bigr) + \frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-\bigl(x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+\bigl(x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}} \mathcal{E}\Bigl(k\bigl(r,x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}\Bigr)\Biggr) \right.} \\
  \medmath{-\left. \frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+\bigl(x + \mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}}}\Biggl(\mathcal{K}\Bigl(k\bigl(r,x + \mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}\Bigr) + \frac{a^{2}-r^{2}-\bigl(x + \mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+\bigl(x + \mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}} \mathcal{E}\Bigl(k\bigl(r,x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}\Bigr)\Biggr)\! \right)}
\end{aligned}\\[3ex]
\raisetag{11.5ex}
        \begin{aligned}B_{r}(r,x)= \medmath{\frac{N I \mu_{0}}{2\pi r} \! \left(\frac{x-\mfrac{d}{2}}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+\bigl(x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}}}\Biggl(-\mathcal{K}\Bigl(k\bigl(r,x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}\Bigr) + \frac{a^{2}-r^{2} + \bigl(x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+\bigl(x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}} \mathcal{E}\Bigl(k\bigl(r,x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}\Bigr)\Biggr) \right.}\\
\medmath{\left. -\frac{x + \mfrac{d}{2}}{\sqrt{(a+r)^{2}+\bigl(x + \mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}}}\Biggl(-\mathcal{K}\Bigl(k\bigl(r,x + \mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}\Bigr) + \frac{a^{2} + r^{2} + \bigl(x + \mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}}{(a-r)^{2}+\bigl(x + \mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}} \mathcal{E}\Bigl(k\bigl(r,x-\mfrac{d}{2}\bigr)^{2}\Bigr)\Biggr)\! \right)}
    \end{aligned}
    \end{gather}
\end{fleqn}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]